# typescript; promise return type mismatch

Tags: angular, typescript, promise

I have a method that compiled fine when i was running the beta of angular 2. now that i upgraded to v4, I'm getting an error I can't seem to solve.

```
uploadPDF(file):Promise<String>
{
  return this.authHttp.get(this.presentationBaseUrl + "presignedUploadURL?file-name="+ encodeURIComponent(file.name))         <<<<< error here
    .toPromise()
    .then( data => {
      var uploadURL = data.json().signedRequest,
      fileURL = data.json().url;

      return this.http.put(uploadURL, file)
              .toPromise()
              .then(response =>{
                return Promise.resolve(fileURL)
              });
    })
    .catch (this.handleError);
}
```

I get `Type 'Promise<Response>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<String>'.`

As far as I can tell my method returns a string at the end of the promise chain (return Promise.resolve(fileURL))

Comment: `return Promise.resolve(fileURL)` is unnecessary. You can return a value at that point, therefore `return fileURL`. Not sure it will fix the issue but worth doing anyway.

Comment: Even simpler, `.then(() => fileURL);`

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Good point, did not resolve the issue unfortunately

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have a guess and it is a hack as there are probably better solutions, but you could attempt to bypass the compiler error by casting the resolved promise to any...

Try this:

```
return this.http.put(uploadURL, file)
          .toPromise()
          .then(response =>{
            return Promise.resolve(fileURL) as any;
          });
```

Comment: It is a hack but it compiles, I actually did .then(() =>fileURL as String). Thx!

Comment: I actually faced similar issues when upgrading my Ionic 2 application to Ionic 3 and switched from typescript 2.0.9 to 2.2.1.
Your hack solves it, but any idea what causes this?

Comment: Not sure, but I am guessing someone changed a function signature in the upgrade.